# an unknown error in php "Undefined variable: try"

Tags: php

in my PHP code user can guess a number. variable 'number' in line 3 has been sent with post method which is in the same page and the code is called by 'PHP_SELF' and 'number' count number of guess but an error occurred in line 3 with this description: Notice: Undefined index: try

```
<?php
$target=13;

$try=(isset($_POST['number'])) ? $try+1 : 1;

if(!isset($_POST['guess'])){
    $message="welcome to geuss machine";}

elseif(!is_numeric($_POST['guess'])){
    $message="inpute is unidentify";}

elseif($_POST['guess']<$target){
    $message="it's to small!";}

elseif($_POST['guess']>$target){
    $message="it's to big!";}

elseif($_POST['guess']=$target){
    $message="you win number was:$target";}

else
    $message="it's confusing!";
?>
```

but in other system is working correctly.
is it related to Apache setting?

Comment: The warning is correct, since `$try` is not defined before line 3. Note, that this is a _warning_, not an _error_. If other systems do _not_ show this warning, then either display of warnings is suppressed in those systems, or they run a much older version of php.

Comment: you mean that in older version of php is work correctly.

Comment: No: as written: the code works, but it spits out a warning, since your code is of questionable quality. Older php versions simply do not warn about this, that is the only difference. Think of it this way: the warning is meant _to help you_ realize that there is a problem in your code. It assists you during the implementation.

Comment: I found the solution. the problem was:

    $try=(isset($_POST['number'])) ? $_POST['number'] +1 : 1;

Comment: Sure, in that line `$try` is not used before it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense:

```
$try=(isset($_POST['number'])) ? $try+1 : 1;
```

means if `number` is set, then increment an undefined variable `$try` +1.

You should initialize it at least to 0 first.

Comment: if I want to count number of guess how can I do that?

Comment: but for the first time the number did not set but in second or third guess the number is set.

Comment: I found the solution. the problem was:

    $try=(isset($_POST['number'])) ? $_POST['number'] +1 : 1;